# Issue with adding DLL reference in VS2015 - C++ DLL

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2015

The error that I am getting is - "Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or com component". Just a note - I have looked at other answers online.

I have created a DLL file in VS10 C++ that I currently reference inside VB.NET application - everything works fine. What I want is to embed DLL into executable file to remove a need for me to send DLL file with EXE file.

I have achieved the desired result with another COM library via references inside VS15. However, the same process for C++ DLL returns the error, which can be found at the beginning of this question.

How can I achieve what I am after with my C++ DLL?

Comment: A pure Win32 DLL cannot be referenced in a .NET project. You've either got to create COM interfaces in your DLL, or convert it into C++/CLI.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/creating-a-com-interface-visual-cpp

Comment: "Embedding" is not an option.  Not much of a problem with a managed assembly since it is just data.  But the OS has a rock-hard requirement that native code is stored in a file on disk.  Copying two files instead of one is not twice has hard.  If you absolutely need one file to deploy, consider naming it setup.exe.  VS2010 still has the "Setup Project" project type.